# Python regex search between > and <

Tags: python, regex

I have this:

```
string = 'white-space:pre;">porttitor,<span class="goog-inline-block" style="width:5.875px;height:16.8px">&nbsp;</span>massa<span class="goog-inline-block" style="width:5.875px;height:16.8px">&nbsp;</span>dui<span class="goog-inline-block" style="width:5.875px;height:16.8px">&nbsp;'
```

and I want this:

```
['porttitor,', '&nbsp;', 'massa', '&nbsp;', 'dui']
```

I have tried `re.findall('^>.*<$', string)` and `re.findall('^\>.*\<$', string)`  but no luck.

I have a non-regex workaround already, so I'm only looking for regex answers. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need an HTML parser.

Comment: https://ideone.com/6yfamg

Comment: You're trying to use the `^` and `$` characters to anchor your match, but those anchors match the beginning and end of the entire input string